# Get certain items from text by position, for loop, python

Tags: python, loops, text

I'm trying to replicate something similar to dictionary like here: https://gist.github.com/anshoomehra/ead8925ea291e233a5aa2dcaa2dc61b2

The code that is used there is

```
document = {}

# Create a loop to go through each section type and save only the 10-K section in the dictionary
for doc_type, doc_start, doc_end in zip(doc_types, doc_start_is, doc_end_is):
    if doc_type == '10-K':
        document[doc_type] = raw_10k[doc_start:doc_end]
```

I'm trying to create a for loop.
I have a list of types and positions (item text starts/ends) like this:

```
zl = [[('Item1', 1263, 42004),
  ('Item2', 42026, 652819),
  ('Item3', 652841, 697154),
  ('Item4', 697176, 705235),
  ('Item5', 705257, 2378296)],
 [('Item1', 1195, 21386),
  ('Item3', 21408, 268339),
  ('Other', 268361, 290688)],
 [('Item1', 1195, 27776),
  ('Item2', 27798, 323951),
  ('Item5', 323973, 348032)]]
```

My loop:

```
final = []

for text in listoftexts:  
    for i in zl: 
        document = {}
        for doc_type, doc_start, doc_end in i:
            if doc_type == 'Item2': 
                document[doc_type] = text[doc_start:doc_end]
    final.append(document)
```

The problem is that it seems to correctly extract only the very first text (doc_start = 42026, doc_end = 652819). All further texts (final[2], final[3]...) are not extracted correctly and seem random.
I'm not sure which part of the loop is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your problem fully
For this snippet:

```
final = []

for text in listoftexts:  
    for i in zl: 
        document = {}
        for doc_type, doc_start, doc_end in i:
            if doc_type == 'Item2': 
                document[doc_type] = text[doc_start:doc_end]
    final.append(document)
```

Tab the `final.append(document)` line so that appending to final only happens if the >key< "item2" is in your list, zl.

```
final = []

for text in listoftexts:  
    for i in zl: 
        document = {}
        for doc_type, doc_start, doc_end in i:
            if doc_type == 'Item2': 
                document[doc_type] = text[doc_start:doc_end]
                final.append(document)
```

With this code you will only extract two texts since "item2" is only in your list zl twice.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that doc_start:doc_end for for second, third, ... text do not seem to come from zl. Also, if I tab final.append(document) it creates way more documents than needed. It seems like it's creating a dictionary for each line.

Comment: @haven Please fully explain to me; What data are you hoping to have by the end of this program?

As I understand it, you just need to get the text from "text" in "listoftexts", if doctype has a string which == 'Item2'.  So at the end you should have a list of iterables (strings?) with length equal to length(listoftexts) * 2 //This number is from how many times item 2 is found in zl}